# protecting against malicious sql injection

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, security

I have a bunch of perl CGIs that take params and use their values in various DBI mySql queries.

Is there any way that a malicious user can do harm (or steal data) from my system if I don't allow any user submitted values that contain the words select, insert, delete, or update to be used as parameters and as long as I wrap all the varchar user provided values in single quotes?

I realize this question is very similar to others asked, but the others all seem to point to various PHP solutions, and I'm not using PHP, so, please forgive the redundancy, or point me to an associated question that answers this specific question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way to handle this in Perl use to use [placeholders](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) in all your SQL queries. Passing user-supplied data via DBI placeholders will ensure that everything is properly quoted. (That doesn't guarantee that it's *secure*, of course, but it will prevent SQL injection.)

Comment: Nitpicky, I know, but placeholders _*do not*_ quote passed values. The structure of the SQL commands and the data which is to be bound to the placeholders are sent to the database separately, which eliminates the need for quoting. The only time placeholders will quote data is when DBI has to fake them because it's dealing with some bargain-basement database backend which doesn't support the real thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameterized queries. Then the user input is not part of the command at all, which is the only reliable way to know the command won't be modified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  What's a parameterized query? I need the user input to be part of the command when the situation is that the user is offering me info about themselves, for example.  Their first name could be "Jack" or it could be "delete from table_a".  Currently I'm simply testing their values against these sorts of malicious strings before sending them through, does your answer address this situation?

Comment: It's another name for the same concept as "placeholders" as in friedo's reply above. The key idea is that the SQL engine should interpret your SQL command *before* it's polluted with any user input.